# Why is debounceTime not working with tap operator

Tags: javascript, rxjs

slightly changed stackblitz from docs:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hg2xdz?file=index.ts

- type into input-field
- check the console output

#### What I want and I expect:

I expect that when I trigger keyup event that the emission of `of(null)` is delayed by the debounceTime. That is not the case here.

- `throttleTime` does not work either
- `delay` seems to work

(my assumption): maybe `of` compleates and therefore debounceTime does not wait for any seconds values ???

Can someone clarify? Thank you

code copy:

```
keyup$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      of(null).pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        tap(() => console.log("tap runs"))
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the source observable completes immediately. `debounce` takes last value in the time window and emits it. Since the operator knows no new value will be emitted when the source observable completed, it emits the value immediately and completes.

Fixing your code would be using `delay`, because you already have the `switchMap` there which emulates the *take last value* logic. But -

I don't know what your use case is, but classical implementation of `debounce` in inputs is much simpler:

```
keyup$
  .pipe(
     debounceTime(1000),
     tap(() => console.log("tap runs")),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: this was  just an example that resembles my problem. Thank you for clarifying my assumptions :-)!